# difficulty in understanding successive recursive calls

Tags: c, recursion, stack

I am trying to understand the following program in which successive recursion function calls are present, but getting confused while tracing how the tack gets loaded.

```
void func(char*);  // function prototype

int main(){
    func("123");
    return 0;
}

void func(char a[]){
    if(a[1]=='\0')
        return;
    func(a+1);
    func(a+1);
    printf("%c",a[1]);
}
```

the output for this is 3 3 2

would appreciate if someone could advise on this one...

does this kind of multiple recursive calls beneficial in any way or find application in specific problem areas..?

Comment: This is the most often used example for recursion (not the website, but the Fibonacci numbers calculation): http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-generate-fibonacci-series

Comment: Indeed, I have used the Fibonacci calculation as an interview question, asking the candidate to create an iterative and recursive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging with breakpoints is one way to understand recursion. Another way is to draw the tree of recursive calls.

[image: Recursive calls tree]

From the figure, In every level after level0, the printf statement occurs after every two nodes owing to these two lines of code:

```
func(a+1);
func(a+1);
```

In general, this becomes a perfect binary tree for any input string of length greater than 0. The total number of nodes is given by this  formula:

```
2^(k+1) - 1 // k is the depth; here k = 2
```

Total number of printf statements executed can be obtained by this formula:

```
2^k - 1 // For k=2, there will be 3 printf statements each printing 3,3,2 respectively
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put yourself in the position of the CPU and step through line-by-line (or use a debugger to help with that task).

The first call is to

```
func("123")
```

this call does not satisfy the termination condition `a[1] == '\0'`, so it calls

```
func("23");
```

The call to func("23") in turn calls

```
func("3")
```

which DOES satisfy the return condition.  So, that call returns to the previous caller, func("23").

func("23") proceeds to make another call to func("3") due to the lines

```
func(a+1);
func(a+1);
```

Continue this process of executing the program in your mind, and write down what would be in each call to `printf`.  That will explain your output.

**UPDATE**

Note that the call to printf() happens *after* the recursive calls, so e.g. a call to

func("123")

would proceed like

- Enter func("123")
- Termination condition not met
- Call func("23")
- Call func("23")  *again*
- Printf("3")  (which is a[1])
- Return

Comment: thanks @Eric and how do I correlate the printf function calls, with the call to func()..?

Comment: For each call into func(), printf() will eventually be called as long as the parameter for func() is more than one character long due to `if (a[1] == '\0') return;`.  The tricky part is that printf() will be called *after* the two calls to `func(a+1)`.  It really boils down to "playing the CPU" and just stepping through.  It may help to print this out on paper and use a pencil to follow along from line to line. If you use a pencil, write down what the parameter is to func() for each call to help you keep track.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code is a rather poorly designed instance of recursion.

The following code has the correct 'tail' form of recursion.

It could be made even better by passing the reversed string back to main and let main print it.

It reverses the order of the string passed to func() by main()

Please, when asking about a runtime problem, post code the compiles, including the necessary #includes for header files so we are not guessing about which headers to include

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char*);  // function prototype

int main(){
    func("123");
    return 0;
}

void func(char a[])
{
    if(a[1]=='\0')   // check for end of recursive sequence
    {
        printf( "%c", a[0] ); // last tail action
        return;
    }

    func(a+1);    // step+next recursion
    printf( "%c", a[0] ); // tail action
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursion can be simply understood as follows.

For example:

```
Func(int a){
    while(a>1)
        return a * func(a-1);
}
```

Suppose `a = 5`.

What happens is that it returns `5 * func(4)`.

Now `func(4)` returns `4 * func(3)` and it goes on like this.

Check out [this example for use of recursion in fibonacci series](http://mycodingclass.com/fibonacci-series-in-c/).